# NgCordova ionic alert

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, ngcordova

```
 angular.module('starter.controllers', [])

    .controller('DashCtrl', function($scope, $cordovaBarcodeScanner) {      
       $scope.scanBLEDevices = function(){
          alert("BLE SCANNING....."); 
       }

    });
```

I am using also NgCordova with Angular Meterial with Ionic and testing on mobile device (Samsung s4) I get the alert twice. 
I think there is a problem with the CALLBACK??

Comment: Provide more information on who is calling scanBLEDevices. It might be called twice

Comment: `<ion-view view-title="Dashboard">
  <ion-content class="padding">
    <h2>BLE Using Evothings</h2>
       <button class="button button-block button-positive" ng-click="scanBLEDevices()"> BLE Scan </button> 
  </ion-content>
</ion-view> This is my code i just call only once.. but it is tiggered twice.` test

Answer (score 0):

It is because, quoted from [this](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/4345#issuecomment-139026496)

> Using window.alert can pause any js going around and prevent proper
>   execution. I did notice that why I switched to the cordova dialogs
>   plugin or ionic's popups, that the issue was gone.
>
> This seems to be the way the browser works, though I'm curious as to
>   why it's not visible on desktop. Not sure what we can do here. But my
>   advice would be to not use window.alerts anyways. Not only to avoid
>   this issue, but not sure the nasty index.htm at the top of the alert.
>   Either the ionic popups or cordova dialogs make for a good
>   alternative.

What is solution for this?

1) Use **$window.alert()** instead.

2) Don't ever bother with that alert, developers don't even use it in desktop-version web; so why bother for mobile app? Style your own alert box. Real-world production alert box, please. Well, you can start with [$ionicPopup](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicPopup/)